# YAML Anchor on same line as alias

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I'm trying to create an alias `rasa-actions-context` whose value itself references another alias.  Is there a way to do that?

```
x-chatbot-server-context:
  chatbot-server-context:
    context: &chatbot-server-context ${GIT_CREDENTIALS}/${ORG}/${REPO}.git#${COMMIT_ID}
  rasa-actions-context:
    context: &rasa-actions-context *chatbot-server-context:rasa_actions_server
```

I get:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 7, column 5
```

Comment: A [YAML anchor](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#id2765878) refers to a whole YAML node (complete sequence, mapping, or scalar); you can't use them for string expansion.  You could have the two `context:`s point at the same physical string but not to include one's content in the other.

Comment: Also you cannot give an anchor for an alias. The alias refers to a node that *already has an anchor*, thus there would be no point in defining another anchor for it.